# C# method for solving missing exponent

Tags: c#

With the equation X^Y = Z, how can I write a c# method, to solve for Y?
Does one already exist?

Here are some examples of the data I will have -

2^Y = 8

3^Y = 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Y=Math.Log(8) / Math.Log(2)
```

Comment: `Y = Math.Log(8, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Math.Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x80ywz41(v=vs.110).aspx).

With that you can do:

```
x = Math.Log(8) / Math.Log(2)
```

Also not that there is a `Math.Log10` which is the logarithm by base 10 - the outcome is yet the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most optimized option but you can iterate through a for-loop of huge amount of numbers, and check one by one iteratively. Just a solution that popped up in my head. Code would look something like:

```
    int base = 2;
    int exponent;
    int result = 8;

for(int i = -9999; i<= 10000000; i++)
{
  exponent = i;
  if(Math.Pow(2,exponent) == result)
{
 WriteLine($"Y = {exponent}");
}
```

Comment: This is definitely over complicated. There are mathematical ways to calculate the required value - like `Math.Log(a) / Math.Log(b)`.

Comment: It is not the best solution, but it does work. Your method is very good and concise I like it!

Comment: This is hardly any viable solution. Even if you're going to find the solution, you will continue the loop - and it will easily overflow after the loop reaching 2^1024.

Comment: @MioBambino, if it finds the solution then just return. And the numbers were arbitrary for the loop starting point and termination condition.

Comment: It does not return. At no point your loop exists, continues, breaks or returns.

Comment: I'm saying you can return, simply return statement.

Comment: @MioBambino, if you read it says not the most optimized option, and first solution that popped up in my head, it does work whether it can cause overflow problems or has bugs, but it definetly is the solution. Now whether it is the worst one, it could be.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how many time Z can be devided by X.

Hope this helps.

```
while (Z > X) 
{
  Z = Z / X;
  Y++;
}
```